# Facebook Video in Fancybox

Tags: wordpress, fancybox

Is there a way to embed Facebook video in fancybox using this code?

```
<a class="overlink" data-fancybox="" href="https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=222587198843939"></a>
```

I am having this error: [image]

Comment: If you could provide a direct link to the video and would set content type to "iframe", then it would work.